# awk/Perl, select different fields and combine them

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

I have stream output in the below format which I like to filter and print out specific fields:

```
customer        $2    $3
Address         $2    $3   $4   $5   $6
```

for example print field#2 from line 1 and print field#6 from line 2 and then print them together separated by space.

Can someone share how this can be done in perl, awk or sed..etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{s=$2;next} {print s ORS $6 ORS s, $6}' file
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me.

How can i further modify this awk line, if I want to print $2 of each line that starts with "customer" and combine it with field $6 from subsequent line. assuming this pattern of lines (customer line, followed by address line) is repeated multiple times in a file or stream.

Comment: Probably just test `NR%2` instead of `NR==1`. If that doesn't do it, post a new question with some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

In awk you can hold data in variables (and use the line number in patterns).  For example, in your sample

> print field#2 from line 1 and print field#6 from line 2 and then print them together separated by space.

The command would be

```
awk 'NR==1 {x=$2} NR==2 {print x " " $6}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^customer/{N;s/^((\S+)\s*){2}.*\n((\S+)\s*){6}.*/\2 \4/p}' file
```

Comment: I get this error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 65: invalid reference \6 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @MubarakAbdallah `\6` should read `\4` see edit.